# Is memtester a good command line memory test?

Tags: memory

I have spent awhile looking for a memory testing tool that works from the command line, and have been unable to find anything besides memtester (http://pyropus.ca/software/memtester/).

Eventually the memory test will be part of a larger stress test, so somethig that runs without an OS (Like memtest86 or memtest86+) will not work here.

Is memtester the only such utility?

Comment: I'm not sure but this utility might not be able to test all the memory since it runs in userspace. Kernel/hardware reserved memory might not be accessible to this utility.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to stress test a loaded system.  Perhaps you are trying to test how well a particular program/system runs?

If you really want to do a memory test, you're better off doing it from a dedicated boot device (boot cd, usb key, etc).  One popular offering is [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/).

If you really, really want to do it on a running system then maybe one of the memory tools within that CD has a userspace port (I doubt it).  If instead you just want a system that is being stressed tested, I'd direct you to look at [stress](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/).  Other ideas can be found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971422/linux-how-to-put-a-load-on-system-memory).